# Grid not displaying properly

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, knockout.js, kogrid

I am using KoGrid for my data representation. This is what it looks like at first:

[image: Initial loaded grid]

When I rotate the phone or tab the grid will display correctly, but I could not figure out how to solve this issue:

[image: problematic rendering]

Has anyone faced this issue?

My Javascript:

```
var vm = {
    myObsArray: ko.observableArray([
        { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' },
        { firstName: 'Jane', lastName: 'Doe' },
        { firstName: 'Jane', lastName: 'Doe' }
    ])
};
ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById("vm"));
```

Html:

```html
<div id="vm">
    <h3>Size (<span data-bind="text: myObsArray().length"></span>)</h3>
    <div class="gridStyle" data-bind="koGrid: { data: myObsArray }"></div>
</div>
```

This is a simple example which I found [here](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/KoGrid/wiki/Getting-Started). Additionally I have used jquery mobile(1.4) with this

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have update with code

Comment: Does the problem still occur if you don't use jQuery Mobile?

Comment: I have not tried that way.

Answer (score 0):

You should write css3 media-queries to correct the display of your data-table in portrait view of mobile or tablet.